# Flutter firebase_storage FirebaseStorage.instance(): The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, profile-picture

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage(storageBucket: '');
```

is deprecated, but when I use

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance();
```

I get this error: The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to use `instanceFor` instead:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instanceFor(bucket: '');
```